# Shade the upper bound of a diagram bounded by some coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to shade the upper bound of the diagram for which the code is given below. Your help is very appreciated. I do not have a specific function, instead, I have specific coordinates that are linked by a line. I would love to shade the upper area bounded by these coordinates.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Policy Importance ($D$)},
    ylabel={Optimal voting Rule $r_{1}*(D)$},
    xmin=1, xmax=100,
    ymin=50, ymax=100,
    xtick={1,5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 55,70, 80, 90, 100},
    ytick={50,67,76,81,86,91,96,100},
    legend pos=outer north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ]
    \addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=*,
    ]
    coordinates {
        (1,51)(2,67)(3,76)(4,81)(6,86)(10,91)(20,96)(50,99)(100,100)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Optimal supermajority rule as a function of policy
importance for continuous decisions.} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular case since the area is bounded by the axis, you can get away with an extra plot directive.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={Policy Importance ($D$)},
ylabel={Optimal voting Rule $r_{1}*(D)$},
xmin=1, xmax=100,
ymin=50, ymax=100,
xtick={1,5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 55,70, 80, 90, 100},
ytick={50,67,76,81,86,91,96,100},
legend pos=outer north east,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot[shade,
top color=blue!10,
bottom color=blue,
draw=blue,
mark=*,
]
coordinates {
    (1,51)(2,67)(3,76)(4,81)(6,86)(10,91)(20,96)(50,99)(100,100)
} -| (rel axis cs:0,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is just amazing! Thanks so much Percusse.

Comment: @JBT Pleasure is mine.